# 2k 5k even 13k same results in render Quality of my material?

Tags: rendering, texture-baking, baking, resolution

[image]

Link to .blend file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SVpp9TP0znxXCh4schhPmfdOI7aP2n9_/view?usp=sharing

My diffuse baking comes out the same way no matter what i do ( yes I did apply all scales , i did try even with 13k to render ). I tried cycles and the other one PBR or whatever is called baking same results.
I dont know what I am missing or doing wrong maybe the shader settings is wrong ?

I want to render a HQ image that when u get close doesnt look like bunch of pixels and is the same on 2 k 4k or 13k (13k was random cause i got mad when at 8k was the same and wanted to do bigger number to see wtf is going on)

Comment: You're mistaken.  Your baking did not come out the same way.  The 9k has more resolution than the 5k.  While I didn't check the 13k (it's kind of painful to get a good test view at the range you need to be able to see the difference) I figure if the 9 is different than the 5, that's enough.  There are other differences between your material, like roughnesses and bump.

Comment: 1st tanks for the reply. Now on the subject i did play around with the matterial to see if I can get it working. As for the result I am going for I would like when u get close to the oboject to be able to see a good quality not big pixels and i dont know what to do.